# How to exclude a file from the assets folder only for release buildType?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

How to exclude a file from the assets folder only for release buildType. Imagine the following scenario:

I have a lot a json strings under the assets folder, with names like string_1.json, string_2.json, string_3.json

With the following snippet I can remove all files.

(gradle snippet)

```
aaptOptions {
    ignoreAssetsPattern "!*.json"
}
```

The problem is I want to keep some and remove some of them. For example, I want to keep string_2.json

Does the ignoreAssetsPattern has something for exclusions?

(Also this snippet will remove both for debug and release. Any help will be appreciated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add additional dir with assets for your debug build for example where this file contains while release build won't have this dir.

Comment: How to do it using build flavors?

Comment: This is should be in android clojure `productFlavors {
        dev {
        }
        prod {
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        dev {
            assets.srcDirs = ['dir1', 'dir2']
        }
        prod {
            assets.srcDirs = ['dir1']
        }
    }`

Comment: I have assets in the src/main/assets. Even with your solution, for dev and prod, these assets will be in the apk (because the main folder is the first being compiled according to android/gradle).

Comment: Just move required assets to additional assets folder for dev flavor.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I had to work a bit my assets folder, and create a new assets folder (with other name) that it's only included on debug.